# About device token

Tags: iphone

Is it possible that device token is null at first time? I have removed white space from 
device token but still it will show null in database.

```
 deviceTokenStr =[[[[deviceToken description]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
   NSLog(@"device token------------%@",deviceTokenStr);
 devicetk=[deviceTokenStr retain];
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceTokenStr);
```

Comment: Do not use the `description` method except for debugging. Apple makes no guarantee that it will remain the same. Use: `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`

Comment: Where is the code that obtains the `deviceToken`? Try NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken); to see it.

Comment: Device token is null at first time. That mean you want to say it'll return value from second time??

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible that device token will return null.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
{
NSString *devicetoken = [[[[devToken description]
                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];


NSLog(@"token :: %@", devicetoken);
}
```